# User List of user roles in List field af a content type

Tags: nodes, entities

I would like to add a new field type in my content type. The field is of the type List(Text) and the possible values should be the list of user roles in the system. Is there a way to do it without creating a custom field type?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Role Field](https://drupal.org/project/role_field) module..

Project page says

> Role Field provides a field for selecting roles that exist in your
>   site.
>
> Please note that there is no out-of-the-box permissions shenanigans
>   going on. It just lets you pick from a list of roles. Although,
>   combined with Rules the possibilities are pretty interesting.